# Vue JS and Multer

Tags: express, vue.js, multer

```
    <template>
      <v-app id="inspire" dark >
       <v-layout v-for = "post in posts" :key = "post.id">
         <v-flex xs3>
           <v-card >
             <v-card-media>
                <img 
       :src = "post.postImage">
             </v-card-media>
             <v-card-title>
               {{post.description}}
             </v-card-title>
           </v-card>
         </v-flex>
       </v-layout>
      </v-app>
    </template>
<script>
import PostService from '@/service/PostService'
export default {
  data(){
    return {
      posts: []
    }
  },
  mounted (){
      this.getPosts()
    },
  methods: {
    async  getPosts() {
      const response = await PostService.fetchPosts()
      this.posts = response.data.posts
    }
  }
}
</script>

    const multer = require('multer');
    const Post = require('./models/post')
    const storage = multer.diskStorage({
        destination: (req, file, cb) => {
            cb(null, './uploads/');
        },
        filename: (req, file, cb ) => {
            cb(null, Date.now() + file.originalname); 
        }
    })

    const fileFilter = (req, file, cb) => {
        if(file.mimetype === 'image/jpeg' || file.mimetype === 'image/png') {
            cb(null, true);
        }else {
            cb(null, false);
        }


    }
    const upload = multer({
        storage: storage, 
        fileFilter,
        limits: {
        fileSize: 1024 * 1024 * 5
    }
    });

app.get('/posts', (req, res) => {
Post.find({},'postImage description', (error, posts) => {
    if(error) {
        console.log(error)
    }
    res.send({
        posts
    })
}).sort({_id: -1})
```

})

Hi all, i was about to display images using multer on my front end. but it does only show imagelink or image destination, but i already added some images in my backend. So how can i show images to my front-end using vue dynamically. I did use v-for for each data in my database. what should i input to my v-card-media to get images dynamically.

Comment: _"So how can i show images to my front-end"_ -> https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/img

Comment: I'd already did that. But i want to get it dynamically. im using v-for

Comment: Where? Can't see any `<img>` elements in your code

Comment: Yeap. I'd tried it many times. like <img :src = "/server/uploads"> that is why im asking how to do it dynamically. Cos i didn't know. Sorry.

Comment: Please look at what you've posted in your question. How can anyone help you solve this problem with the information you've shown?

Comment: I am so sorry. My point is in the <v-card-media> where i would wanted to get the images dynamically. </server/uploads/> this is the link to my images.